# Physics law in this statement, if there are any

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinetic-theory, molecular-dynamics

happened to find an interesting line and would like to know if there is any law in physics which confirms even partially that and, if so, which is/are these laws (so that I can look up for them myself, not to bother you...)
"If you tap a pillar of a building repeatedly, you create a rhythm. And if you tap long enough and consistently enough, eventually it will answer back, frequencies will align, molecule will scramble and the whole building will collapse from within". Is it any physics in this or is just a metaphoric line from a movie? Thanks.K.

Comment: Google 'resonant frequency'

Answer (score 2):

It is describing a [mechanical resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_resonance). A force will cause the building to move a bit in response, moving back after a certain time. A periodic force may, if it has the right frequency, add more energy every time to this sway. If it has the wrong frequency things will average out and it will not contribute any net energy. Over time a resonant force can build up enough energy in the oscillations that the building crashes.

So just tapping a building will not work, it has to be at the right resonant frequency (which for big objects is fairly slow). The pattern of tapping is also largely irrelevant: you want to drive a particular resonant frequency, adding extra harmonics to it is likely useless.

The classic textbook example is [soldiers marching over a bridge accidentally inducing resonance causing it to collapse](https://www.historyandheadlines.com/april-12-1831-marching-soldiers-cause-suspension-bridge-collapse/). Some actual building collapses involve wind creating periodic forces through vortex shedding.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by humans, with a wine glass, as the nearest comparison  I can make to  destroying something by repeating "tapping".

But for a building of any size, even a Lego brick house, it won't work, at least not by a human finger tapping it.

The glass will break because it's both very light and composed of one material.

A building has many parts, starting with the different chemical  compounds within the brick you tap. These  all have a different resonance frequency and (even ignoring the mass involved),  resonance effects will be damped out immediately.